# Pledge reminder emails sending out invalid payment links

Tags: civicontribute, pledges

Periodically, we have people complaining that their pledge reminder email has a link that doesn't work.  They get the "0 Error" with text "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment."  If I edit the pledge and change something in the Payment Reminders section, the next email they receive will contain a link that is exactly the same but will have a different number after "cs=" and it will then work as it should.

This is in CiviCRM 4.4.5 but I can't find any issues in the issue tracker that seem to be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be an issue about the checksum that has a lifetime of (by default( 7 days. I suppose that's the ones taking more than a week that experience that problem?

you can set a longer lifetime in the admin misc setting
/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1

Comment: One question though: What is the recommended way of making the system send a new email once the allotted number has been sent.  It seems that making a change in the Payment Reminders section of the pledge will cause it to send again but that seems like a hack.  There should be a way to zero out the "Reminders sent" count.